# Regex without specific string before slash

Tags: regex

Im trying to create a regex for JS parser, with following values

Passed:

```
@angular/core
d3
@angular/grid
rxjs/subject
```

Not passed:

```
@grid/workflow
```

But this regex with lookahead does not work https://regex101.com/r/4WGUGY/1

Comment: Use: `/^(?!@grid).+\/*.*$/gm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
/^(?!@grid).+\/*.*$/gm
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4WGUGY/3)